# How to remove Error: Value of Type "UniSimdesign.realvariable" cannot be converted to "Double"

Tags: vb6

```
 Dim usdInFlow2 As UniSimDesign.ProcessStream 
 Dim InF1 As Double
 Dim InF2 As Double
 Dim OutF As Double

    InF1 = 1.1
    InF2 = usdInFlow2.MolarFlow
```

---

In above code, the last statement gives error that :

Value of Type "UniSimdesign.realvariable" cannot be converted to "Double".

Can some one answer how to get rid of this error? 
Note that UniSimdesign is referenced type library and this code was working fine in VB 2006.

Comment: This obviously is not VBScript. Did you mean VB6 or VB.net?

Answer (score 0):

MolarFlow is an Object type that cannot be cast to a Double.  Try Using

```
InF2 = usdInFlow2.MolarFlowValue.
```

which I believe is defined as a Double.